# Suddenly, NPM script variables no longer work

Tags: windows, variables, npm, package.json

I use `package.json` variables like this in NPM scripts:

```
// package.json
{
  "version": "0.12.1",
  "scripts": {
    "get-version": "echo %npm_package_version%"
  }
}
```

`npm run get-version` currently echoes `%npm_package_version%` instead of `0.12.1`. In the past, the scripts worked without any problems. Suddenly only the variable name comes back. With multiple repositories. I run Windows 10 2004 and NodeJS v15.4.0.

Was there a change for NPM scripts in Node.js 15? Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: I'm on macOS, so that doesn't work either way. But `"get-version": "echo $npm_package_version"` works the same (showing the actual version) in Node 14 and 15.

Comment: For cross-platform consider utilizing [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var) then you can utilize a single syntax, i.e. use the dollar prefix `$...` instead of `%...%`. For instance; `"get-version": "cross-var echo $npm_package_version"`

Comment: Btw. If you `cd` to your project directory and run `npm run env` you can verify whether the `npm_package_version` exists in the list of environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. `npm run env` works and lists `npm_package_version`. Do not understand why `%npm_package_version%` doesn not work anymore.  The trick with `cross-var` works, after installation with `npm install cross-var --save-dev`.

Comment: Does not seem to work with cross-var with npm 6+. No matter what guide I find on trying to pass a variable to an npm script, none seem to work. `%npm_package_NAME%`, `%npm_config_NAME%`, `%NAME%`, `$npm_package_NAME`, `$npm_config_NAME`, `$NAME`. Nothing lets me pass a variable and give it a name to be used in a script. Probably should of just asked my own question to include all the research I have done, but about every guide I could find on the subject in the last 5 years does not work anymore in npm 6+.

I have at this point given up and just hope this question gets more attention.

Comment: @JordanRamstad: What does `npm config get script-shell` show?

Comment: @JordanRamstad "trying to pass a variable to an npm script" - Like this? `npm run myScript -- --myArg`?  https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_1

Comment: @entitycs Yes, I want to pass a variable I can utilize inside webpack config, I have tried about every method to do so and despite it working with yargs and something like `npm run dev -- $variable` and having access to `argv.variable` in node v10 (npm v4 or 5) or so, as soon as I tried to update node for other reasons it stopped working (node-gyp.....). I was no longer able to see the arguments passed to the script within the webpack config. Currently I changed to using env variables, which does work at least, but is really cumbersome.

Comment: @JordanRamstad - your issue(s), which I don't fully understand what they are, may be related to [this rfcs](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0021-reduce-lifecycle-script-environment.md) regarding reducing the environment variables provided to lifecycle scripts. However, in the case of this OP, the `npm_package_version` env var will be preserved, so that should be ok..

Comment: Basic trouble-shooting should start at typing "where cmd.exe" to verify that the PATH is still good and the expected version of cmd.exe is found and "set comspec" to verify that the environment is still good.

Comment: @JordanRamstad I'm still not following exactly. Is this not the solution for named variables, in all environments?  `npm run dev -- --variable`

Comment: @entitycs yes, though now I do see this question, while related is not exactly the same as my issue (I tried it as a solution and it also did not work), putting the bounty up was probably a bit hasty, should of made my own question. Basically I want to be able to run an npm script and pass a variable from the cli, and have that accessible to node scripts. I have yet to find a valid solution for that and have resorted to using env variables. However how I described it in my last comment worked in previous versions, defining the variable like `$variable` in package.json.

Comment: @JordanRamstad From the windows command line, `npm start -- --myArg=123` will pass 'myArg=23' into server.js, which can be accessed from `argv[2]`... so I'm still confused as to your question.  I think it's best you do create a new question. Lay out your project hierarchy - describe where you want your argument to be entered (windows cli) and where you want to access it (webpack config).  Spell out the exact command on the cli you want, along with the exact file you want to access that argument from.  Perhaps there is some missing link in between those two points where the argument gets lost.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: Failure to expand environment variables on Windows appears to be [a recent high-priority known bug in the npm CLI](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2731).

Because this is `npm@7` specific, until a fix is released, you can downgrade to `npm@6`.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

The easiest solution for the specific case in this question is to use `node`.

```
    "get-version": "node -p process.env.npm_package_version"
```

This will work on every platform that Node.js supports.

If you need a more general solution and don't want to rewrite a bunch of scripts to use `node`, you can try [`cross-var`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var) as mentioned by [@RobC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1611459/robc) in the comments.

As for the source of the problem, perhaps you are running under the Windows bash shell, in which case you can use this:

```
    "get-version": "echo $npm_package_version"
```

That won't work for non-bash Windows environments though.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to the bug and a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I found simple hack which is working perfect in my case,

### Specifically in your use case

```
// package.json
{
  "version": "0.12.1",
  "scripts": {
    "get-version": "node -e \"console.log(process.env.npm_package_version)\""
  }
}
```

Usage

> `npm run get-version`

### However you want to pass arguments.

```
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "get-argument": "node -e \"console.log('your argument:',  process.argv[1] )\"",
  }
}
```

Test example

> `npm run get-argument hello_world`

Comment: Windows `cmd` will throw an error when running your 2nd example because of the single quotes encasing the JS. For cross-platform consider:  **1)**  Changing the quoting in your 2nd example to: `"get-argument": "node -e \"console.log('your argument:',  process.argv[1] )\""`. _Note: the single quotes now encase the `'your argument'` string, and all the JS is encased in JSON escaped double quotes  (`\"...\"`)_. **2)** Similarly, your 1st example should be `"get-version": "node -e \"console.log(process.env.npm_package_version)\""`, _i.e. encase the JS in JSON escaped double quotes_.

Comment: Thanks for you Attention @RobC,

Answer (score 0):

Default values are a great way to handle undefined values. We use a predefined value instead. Inside our NPM script we can achieve that by using the following syntax;

```
{
  "version": "0.12.1",
  "scripts": {
    "get-version": "echo ${npm_package_version:0.99}"
  }
}
```

And of course, running npm from a bash prompt might help.   I guess running from a  Cmd/Powershell "could work" but I would be careful about that.

Comment: If you're wanting to use default values then your syntax is incorrect. What you want is [`${npm_package_version:-2.0.0}`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) i.e. you're missing a hyphen. This ensures that if `npm_package_version` is unset or null the expansion of e.g. `2.0.0` is substituted. Otherwise, the value of `npm_package_version` is substituted. _(Note: the shell npm utilizes for running scripts on *nix is `sh` by default, and `cmd` on windows, therefore parameter expansion will only work successfully in the former scenario.)_

Answer (score 0):

FYI - A related change in Version 7 if you are using the Package config variables:
The variable name changed from npm_package_config_customFooVar in V6 to npm_config_customFooVar in V7
Delineate these appropriate (as below) to the environment (Windows bash linux etc) being used. or Use lib like cross-var.

Package.json

```js
{
  "config": {
    "customFooVar": "bar",
    "env": "development"
   },
  "scripts": {
    "get-var": "echo using env1 $npm_config_customFooVar OR env2 %npm_config_customFooVar%"
    "build": "npm config set myAppName:env"
    "postbuild": "cross-var ng build --configuration=$npm_config_env && cross-var node myOtherBuildSript.js $npm_config_env"
  }
} 

e.g. npm-cli call (note space after --) as this is passed to the script. Not to npm itself.

npm run build -- production
```

Answer (score 0):

pass args from package.json to cli
echo %npm_package_version%

Answer (score 0):

This solution allowed me to use the `npm_package_version` variable in both Windows and Unix:
Install `run-script-os` as a dev dependency. Then in your `package.json` the variable can be used:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "postversion": "yarn postversion-wrapper",
    "postversion-wrapper": "run-script-os",
    "postversion-wrapper:windows": "echo %npm_package_version%",
    "postversion-wrapper:nix": "echo $npm_package_version"
}
```